Automorphism group of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$
This question is related to this answer by Prof. Holt.
I can see why ${\rm PGL}_2(p)$ induces the full automorphism group of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$. Let $a$ be any automorphism of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$. I can also see why we may assume that $a$ centralizes $S$. I'd like to use Frattini Argument: since ${\rm PGL}_2(p)\le{\rm Aut}({\rm PSL}_2(p))=:X$ acts $2$-transitively on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$, by Frattini Argument we have that $X=(N_X(S)\cap N_X(P)) {\rm PGL}_2(p) $, where $P$ is another Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$. Then $a=bc$ for any $a\in X$, where $b\in N_X(S)\cap N_X(P)$ and $c\in {\rm PGL}_2(p)$. Since ${\rm PGL}_2(p)$ induces the full automorphism group of $S$, it follows that there exists $c’\in {\rm PGL}_2(p)$ such that $x^{c’}=x^b$ for any $x\in S$. Consequently $a’:=bc’^{-1}\in C_X(S)$. It indicates that for any $b\in N_X(S)$ there exists $a’\in C_X(S), c’ \in {\rm PGL}_2(p)$ such that $b=a’c’$.
There are two questions:

I don’t see why may assume further that $a$ normalizes other Sylow $p$-subgroup, say $P$. Indeed, we have that $a’\in C_X(S)$. But that does not guarantee $a’\in N_X(S)\cap N_X(P)$.

Suppose that an automorphism centralizes a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$ and normalizes another Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$. Why does that force the automorphism must be $1$? In this case I know that this automorphism normalizes all the Sylow $p$-subgroups and hence this automorphism is in the kernel of the action of $X$ on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of ${\rm PSL}_2(p)$. But $X$ is not simple or anything like that so how do we know that the kernel is $1$? Or am I confusing anything? Thank you.



For Question 1, $S$ acts transitively by conjugation on the $p$ Sylow $p$-subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ other than $S$, so we can multiply $a'$ by an element of $S$ to make it fix some other Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$.
For Question 2, the kernel of the action of $X$ on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups would be disjoint from ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$, so it would centralize ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$, contradicting the fact that it is a group of automorphisms thereof.
